# jQuery autocomplete not finding $(this) inside $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I have a MVC application which is using the autocomplete as in link [1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete.aspx). Then, to be able to format the display, I have passed a complex JSON object with this JSON schema:

```
{
   "name": "searchResults",
   "properties": {
        "Id": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "Table.ID, maps to value",
            "required": true
        },
        "Name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Display name, maps to label",
            "required": true
        },
        "Type": {
            "type": "number",
            "description": "Table selector (enum)",
            "required": true
        }
   }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use `$(this)` inside the `$.ajax` function. I tried using context, but it is not working. I keep receiving *"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"*. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
  $('*[data-autocomplete-url]').each(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          // THIS WORKS!
          //url: $('*[data-autocomplete-url]').data('autocomplete-url'),
          // THIS DOESN'T WORK!
          url: $(this).data('autocomplete-url'),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
          data: {
            token: $("#tags").val()
          },
          success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
              return {
                label: item.Name,
                value: item.Id
              };
            }));
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
          }
        });
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#tagsId").val(ui.item.value);
        event.preventDefault();
      },
      focus: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
        event.preventDefault();
      },
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the Razor snippet:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" data-autocomplete-url="@Url.Action("Search", "Search")" />
    <input id="tagsId" hidden="hidden" />
</div>
```

Is there a way to use `$(this)` to get the specific autocomplete element responsible for firing the action?

**References:**

[ASP.NET MVC & jQuery UI autocomplete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/04/23/asp-net-mvc-amp-jquery-ui-autocomplete.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ajax function `this` not works, as it does not have scope to the reference of the element.

you need to store a copy of this before making the ajax request:

```
var url =  $(this).data('autocomplete-url');
```

and in ajax call use that variable:

```
url:url
```

Comment: Issue is not regarding ajax method but source callback method where `this` isn't referring to element but to plugin itself so using context option set to `this` shouldn't work AFAIK

Comment: As @A.Wolff said, `context` doesn't work. But using the variable does.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure variable inside `each` loop or get element using inside `source` callback method:

```
url: $(this.element).data('autocomplete-url'),
```